# $A$ finite implies $P(A)$ finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A$ finite implies $P(A)$ finite

Let $X=\{0,1\}$

$A $ finite $\rightarrow$ $\exists f:[n]\to A$ a bijection for some $n\in N$

define. $g:X^{n}\to P(A)$

$$(x_i)_{i\in [n]} \mapsto \{f(i) \;|\; x_i =1 \}$$

Then this is a bijection

Is this proof okay?

Comment: Assuming you've proven $X^n$ is finite, it's fine.

Comment: Yes I have proved finite product of finite sets is finite

Comment: Have you also proved that the image of a finite set (under a function) is finite?